# Enzyme Shallow() returns an element that doesn't work with selectors correctly

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, chai-enzyme

I expected this to work but it doesn't:

```
const element = shallow(<SomeComponentClass />);
element.is(SomeComponentClass); // === false, why?
```

I get false although I was expecting it to return true.
Using `mount()` instead of `shallow()` returns `true`

Why?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an issue for enzyme about this and it seems like shallow doesn't return the component class but the rendered dim element. 
https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/768#issuecomment-272125380

So the false is intentional. 
Mount should also return false, actually.